# How to run a Scenario as a Given step before further scenarios

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, cypress

I'm using Cypress & Cucumber to automate a website that allows the user to search, then open and edit the things in a list... So I have a generic initial scenario like this;

```
Scenario: A valid user can navigate to & Search Things
    Given I have submitted "valid" user credentials
    When I am taken to the dashboard
    And I navigate to Manage Things
    Then I make a generic search for things
```

Step defs ;

```
Given('I have submitted {string} user credentials', (userType)=>{
    let user = userType === 'valid' ? testUser1 : new User('test@test.test', 'test1234')
    userLogin(user)
})

When('I am taken to the dashboard', ()=>{
    homepage.mainHome().should('be.visible')
})


And('I navigate to Manage Things', () =>{
    homepage.homeThings().click()
    homepage.thingsManageThings().click()
    cy.get('.form-header').should('contain', 'Things')
})

Then('I make a generic search for things', () =>{
    thingsMenu.manageThingsSearch().click()
    thingsMenu.manageThingsTable().should('be.visible')
})
```

Going forward, I want the next few scenarios/tests to run this scenario before continuing with more steps - Ideally I would have something like `Given A valid user can navigate to & Search Things` followed by `When I select edit on the first thing` etc. ... How would I wrap this `Scenario` as `Given` step? I have looked at using `before()` statements but didn't seem to answer the question of running a whole scenario before...?

Comment: You can use `Background` above all of your scenarios. 
`Background: A valid user can navigate to & Search Things
    Given I have submitted "valid" user credentials
    When I am taken to the dashboard
    And I navigate to Manage Things
    Then I make a generic search for things`

Comment: @HamzaFarooq is correct. We run cucumber-java features with Selenium and 80% of them use Background scenario for all scenarios within the feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the Background section in your feature files.
See info [here](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#background-section).

```
Feature: My feature

    Description of my feature

    Background: this will run before each scenario
        Given A valid user can navigate to & Search Things
        And .....
        
    Scenario: #1
        When I select edit on the first thing
        Then ...

    Scenario: #2
        Given ...
        When ...
        Then ...
```